# Скачать файл и сохранить в папку приложения

Tags: java, android, сеть

Необходимо, чтобы приложение загружало файл из интернета, например, с google-диска, и сохраняло его в одну из своих папок.
То, что я уже пробовала сделать, не работает, например такое:

```
try {
                URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TMQ-LIA6GsV3ZhdU10eThjblU");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

                File f1 = new File("1.txt");
                FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(f1);

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int count = 0;

                while ((count=bis.read(b)) != -1)
                    fw.write(b,0,count);

                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
```

При запуске приложение закрывается и пишет: "Unfortunately, *приложение* has stopped".
Как исправить это приложение или по-другому код написать???

В манифесте прописано

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.
```

Comment: Конкретно у гугл-диска [есть API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) , которое позволяет более комфортно работать с файлами, хранящимися на этом ресурсе. То есть, во первых он не подходит для обобщающего примера, а во вторых с гугл-диском работают по другому. Уточните что вам нужно все же , именно гугл-диск или абстрактный файл где-то на сервере в интернете.

Comment: Кроме того, если проблема связана с падением, необходимо приложить стэктрейс (лог) при падении. "Unfortunately .." стандартный ответ для пользователя, разработчику он **не говорит ни о чем**

Comment: Да, мне нужно именно с гугл-диска скачивать файл

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы вручную создавать стрим к файлу, просим Андроид дать стрим. Если код сверху действительно получает доступ к URL и все нормально читается, то код снизу тоже должен работать.

```
FileOutputStream fw;

try {
    fw = openFileOutput("1.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;

    while ((count=bis.read(b)) != -1)
        fw.write(b,0,count);

    fw.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
     // ignore
}
```

Также следует помнить, что все сетевые операции должны выполняться в отдельном (не UI) потоке.